# Which database type for log analysis?

Tags: mysql, index, nosql, logs, graph

I am running a database for log analysis. At the moment I use a MySQL database and the table for my analysis looks like this:

- UUID
- REQUEST_ID
- REQUEST_TIMESTAMP
- RESPONSE_TIMESTAMP
- RUNTIME
- SERVER_NAME
- EXSIGHT_NAME

I use this table to create views for each entry, for 5 minute aggregation and for a daily aggregation. I am inserting about 400.000 entries a day. At the moment there are about 70 Million rows in this table.

My actual problem is, that my queries are getting slow, my insert/update queries as well as my aggregation queries.

So I created a second table for my daily aggregation. Once a day a job will run, to make an aggregation for the last day. A second job will delete all entries which are older than 30 days from the original table.

My question:
Is this the right approach or would be a different table structure or even a another database (e.g. NoSQL, Graphdatabase, etc.) better?

[EDIT]

Select for daily aggregation:

```
select 
        date_format(REQUEST_TIMESTAMP,'%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') as INTERVAL_START,
        null as INTERVAL_END,
        count(REQUEST_ID) as Anzahl,
        FORMAT((sum(RUNTIME)/count(REQUEST_ID))/1000,0) as dStime 
    from REQUEST_LOGS 
        where EXSIGHT_NAME like (case when '<EXSIGHT>' = 'alle' then '%' else '<EXSIGHT>' end) 
        and SERVER_NAME like '<SERVER>' 
        and (REQUEST_TIMESTAMP between '<FILTERFROMDATE>' and '<FILTERTODATE>')
    group by INTERVAL_START
    order by INTERVAL_START desc
```

Indexes:

[image]

Comment: My first guess is that a few properly placed indexes will help you out better than changing engines.  Could you post any existing indexes as well as what your aggregate query looks like and what it groups on?

Comment: added information about indexes and an example query

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; something is confusing in the Pos column of the index list.

Comment: I'm confused.  You say "daily aggregation" as if you do the same query each day.  Yet there seem to be parameters passed to the query.  I want move you toward a _constant_ set of aggregation queries each day; put the results in Summary table(s); then get the _real_ aggregation from the summary.  It will be a little more work, but so fast that you can build a web page to let users get whatever they want (within limits).

Answer (score 1):

You need several of my blogs:

- [*Why UUIDs can be very slow*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid) - Do you need a UUID?
- [*How to efficiently purge "older than X days"*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint) using `PARTITIONing`;
- [*Incrementally augmenting a Summary Table*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables), though you may have this 'right'.

How big is the table?  Which Engine are you using?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  It should be about 70% of RAM.

Comment: At the moment I don't need the UUID. It is created in my Java Class an not in the database. Additionally it is not included in the an index. I thought that my UUID will be processed like a common varchar or am I wrong?

Comment: When a table gets do big that many actions are I/O-bound, performance suffers.  This applies regardless of the "database type" in use.  Getting rid of UUID would be a small step in that direction.